# How can I change a div image and height rules when screen is resized?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two divs side by side, chat_bubble and character_image. The chat_bubble is a fixed percentage of the screen width/height, and the character_image fills the rest of the space. If the screen width is too small to fit both, character_image is tiled underneath and cuts off the image vertically to make space for chat_bubble.

I want to change this so that if the character_image must be tiled underneath chat_bubble:

1. The image is changed to a new image
2. That new character_image is now a fixed height and width of the screen, and for chat_bubble to fill the remaining vertical space.
3. chat_bubble needs to be 100% width of the screen when character_image is underneath, instead of 70%.

What's the best way for me to do this? I am doing this as a JavaScript project, do I need to add if conditions to my JavaScript to do this or can it be done responsively through CSS?

Here's my code pen to show how it is now:

https://codepen.io/TheNomadicAspie/pen/JjWVbKJ

Here's the relevant CSS code:

```
#main {
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#chat_bubble    {
    width: 70%;
    height: 70%;
    background: ghostwhite !important;
    float: left;
}

#character_image  {
    max-height: 30vh;
    object-fit: cover;
    background: #ffffff;
    float: right;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to load a new image using javascript but make the theme/image responsive.
First, make sure HTML doctype is HTML5 `<!DOCTYPE html>` and contains the meta tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`
Then, apply css like for desktop view.

```
#chat_bubble    {
  width: 70%;
  background: ghostwhite !important;
  float: left;
}
  #character_image  {
  width:30%;
  float: right;
}
#character_image>img{
  width:100%
}
```

For mobile view, using media query for mobile. For example

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    #chat_bubble, #character_image{
      width:100%;
      float:none;
    }
    
}
```